# Trying to use curl to get information but getting http error

Tags: php, xml, curl, parameters, method-call

So I have this code below. However, every time I try to execute it I get a `is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500` error. I am unsure as to why.

```
<?php
    $newname=1;
    $cid=(curl -s -q "http://secure.imvu.com/catalog/skudb/gateway.php" -X POST -d "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>gateway.getUserIdForAvatarName</methodName>
<params>
<param><value><string>$newname</string></value></param>
</params></methodCall>" | tr "<int>" "\n" | grep -i [0-9] | tail -1);
    echo $cid;
?>
```

Error:

```
[02-Dec-2018 12:53:39 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"http://secure.imvu.com/catalo' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in test.php on line 3
```

Comment: How should we know what that service refuses to serve your request? Ask the operator of that service!

Comment: @arkascha The issue is not on the service side. It doesn't at all load my php page

Comment: An http status 500 is ALWAYS something actively sent from the requested server. Where else should it come from? Your php code most likely is executed and crashes. That definitely happens on the server side, where else?

Comment: @arkascha I get this error in the error log: `[02-Dec-2018 12:35:42 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in test.php on line 2
[02-Dec-2018 12:35:44 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in test.php on line 2`

Comment: OK, great, you performed your first debugging session! So you have a syntax error in that line. Do you spot it? `cid` should be `$cid`. You understand why your version throws a syntax error? The same is true further down with `avicid`...

Comment: @arkascha I fixed all of the variables. But now I get a new error `[02-Dec-2018 12:44:22 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in test.php on line 2`

Comment: `$(curl...` also is no valid php, not sure why you think it is. Not sure what you try to do there. Likewise further down: `$(echo $cid);`.

Comment: Apparently you try to execute a shell command from within php. That is not done the way you try. Maybe you should first read a bit about the tools you are using. I suggest you learn about php's `curl` extension which will make things easier for you.

Comment: Why did you accept the answer @Joe gave below? It does not at all answer the question...

Comment: @arkascha I accidentally clicked it. I undid it. Also I updated my code and error. My goal is to create a post request with the url I provided `gateway.php` and give it the `cid` which is an int. Then it should output me a string.